# Scrapy Extract Script Value

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

Using the scrapy shell on a specific url I am trying to identify how I can extract the author value or contributor value out of this script within a pages source code? I have tried

```
response.xpath('//script').re(r'author":"([0-9.]+)"')
```

this is the script in the source code of the site

```
<script charSet="UTF-8">...
"author":"3810161","contributor":{"id":"3810161"}},
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @avin How do I get the author value of 3810161 via scrapy?

Comment: What's the output of what you tried?

Comment: Try changing it to `response.xpath('//script').re(r'author":"([0-9.]+?)"') ` . Note the `?` added after `+` for non greedy capture

Comment: still not getting the value from [this page](https://www.shutterstock.com/search/?site=image&image_type=vector&searchterm=&page=1&studio=1)

Comment: I have even tried 
    response.xpath('//script[contains(text(),"author")]/text()').re(r'"auth
    ...: or":"([0-9.]+?)"')

Answer (score 0):

Did you try printing all the `<script>` contents from Scrapy itself?
I guess you will not see the same content as you see in your navigator inspector since theses nodes appear to be Javascript rendered and Scrapy don't handle Javascript.

If you just want to extract some content from theses search results, you could just use the [api](https://www.shutterstock.com/sstk/api/footage/images/search?site=image&image_type=vector&q=&page%5Bnumber%5D=2=1&studio=1include=contributor-limited-meta) (Same search parameter you posted, but give you a JSON response, really more easy to parse...)

Comment: thanks @clement where did you find these api docs? looks like it only shows one page of results when i try to change your example to page=2 or more it just shows the same result?

Comment: I found this url by looking at the "XHR" tab on the chrome inspector, I suggest that you start from inspecting the AJAX requests when you try to crawl something, it can make your life much more easier ;)
As for the "page" parameter, my bad it should be "page%5Bnumber%5D=2"